# PathTooLong error with Get-ChildItem in PowerShell v3, but not v2

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-3.0, get-childitem

On a [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 VM, I upgraded PowerShell to v3 hoping to take advantage of the [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) (gci) performance improvement. This line ran without error in v2:

```
$search = gci $dir -recurse -exclude "*.mdf" | where {$_.length -gt 100mb}
```

After upgrading to v3, why does the same line give this error? The `$dir` value is unchanged.

> gci : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less
>   than 248 characters.
>   At line:1 char:11
>   + $search = gci $dir -recurse -exclude "*.mdf" | where {$_.length -gt 100mb}
>   +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\server.domain...DETAILS 1.0.prt:String) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

There is no change after applying Windows Updates and rebooting. I took a snapshot of the VM before upgrading PowerShell, so I have the luxury of toggling back and forth easily.

`$errorActionPreference` is `Continue` in both v2 and v3.

`$search.count` is 8 in both v2 and v3, so I'm not super concerned about missing stuff, but would like to understand the change in behavior.

I tried addding `-force` in v2, saw similar PathTooLong errors, and `.count` is 10. After adding `-force` in v3, `.count` was 9. I then reverted to v2 and again found 10 files with `-force`. It's nevertheless possible that changing data under `$dir` could explain the `.count` difference, but in our environment, changing data couldn't realistically explain the consistent presence of PathTooLong errors in v3, but not v2. Now that my curiosity has gotten the better of me, I'm hoping someone has a lead on this mystery and will spare me the error handling which, I admit, might offer more clues.

FWIW, the [usage documentation on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) says it applies to both v2 and v3. The `-Force` parameter's default value is False.

[Some background](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/276235/path-length-limitations) on PowerShell and `MAX_PATH` from the v1 days.

On a [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 VM, I upgraded PowerShell to v3 hoping to take advantage of the [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) (gci) performance improvement. This line ran without error in v2:

```
$search = gci $dir -recurse -exclude "*.mdf" | where {$_.length -gt 100mb}
```

After upgrading to v3, why does the same line give this error? The `$dir` value is unchanged.

> gci : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less
>   than 248 characters.
>   At line:1 char:11
>   + $search = gci $dir -recurse -exclude "*.mdf" | where {$_.length -gt 100mb}
>   +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\server.domain...DETAILS 1.0.prt:String) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

There is no change after applying Windows Updates and rebooting. I took a snapshot of the VM before upgrading PowerShell, so I have the luxury of toggling back and forth easily.

`$errorActionPreference` is `Continue` in both v2 and v3.

`$search.count` is 8 in both v2 and v3, so I'm not super concerned about missing stuff, but would like to understand the change in behavior.

I tried addding `-force` in v2, saw similar PathTooLong errors, and `.count` is 10. After adding `-force` in v3, `.count` was 9. I then reverted to v2 and again found 10 files with `-force`. It's nevertheless possible that changing data under `$dir` could explain the `.count` difference, but in our environment, changing data couldn't realistically explain the consistent presence of PathTooLong errors in v3, but not v2. Now that my curiosity has gotten the better of me, I'm hoping someone has a lead on this mystery and will spare me the error handling which, I admit, might offer more clues.

FWIW, the [usage documentation on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) says it applies to both v2 and v3. The `-Force` parameter's default value is False.

[Some background](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/276235/path-length-limitations) on PowerShell and `MAX_PATH` from the v1 days.

Comment: you can use this .net assembly http://alphafs.codeplex.com/ to avoid the   `PathTooLongException`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that the PathTooLongException is not specific to PowerShell. It is thrown by the Win32 APIs that are called behind the scene. If you must work with long paths, you might find out if PowerShell will allow you to make use of the Unicode versions of the Win32 APIs instead. [See here for information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx)

As for why version 2 did not throw the error, I can only presume that version 2 had "better" internal handling of the exception.

Comment: Thanks, i did see that article, and may try the workaround. And I agree, all signs so far point to v2 keeping quiet about that error. I'm still curious what was the relevant change between versions, though my qn is starting to seem merely academic...

Comment: One important difference between v2 and v3 of Powershell is the version of the .NET CLR it runs on top of. Powershell v2 ran using the .NET 2.0 CLR (not to be confused with .NET Framework v2.0) whereas Powershell v3 runs using the .NET 4.0 CLR (again, not to be confused with the .NET Framework 4.0). The 4.0 CLR is a LOT less forgiving about exceptions.